# How to keep Javascript loading animation smooth while heavy rendering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, angular-material

We are developing a WebApp on AngularJS and Angular-Material.
For collecting input data we created a Wizard which consists of nested Tabs. 
The Performance can get rather poor when you are running Internet Explorer.

The problem can be seen here in action:

```
/* http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyjBLz */
/* (Compare on IE and any Chrome / Firefox / Safari)*/
```

So my question is:

Is it possible to show a loading animation that will be independent from the rendering process to at least make it look like the app would be running smoothly in IE?

Comment: The only way I know is to set an animated gif that `ng-hide`s when the app has finished loading.